# Setting a default user for startunity

Tags: unity, gnome

I have installed Ubuntu via Crouton on my ChromeBook.
So far, everything works fine.

The problem is, it starts with the normal user that was set up. 
I have enabled the root account, and set a password (as usual). 
Now I want to login (graphically) as root.

The way I start gnome now is: `sudo startunity.`
How can I start it as root ? 
When I click on logout, it just shuts the gnome session down.

It seems that part of the answer is doing something like:

```
sudo enter-chroot
su root --> enter password 
startunity
```

Now the only question remaining is how to set the default user, so I don't have to enter the password every time....

Comment: Why is this off-topic?  See http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7095/chrubuntu-questions-on-topic-or-off-topic .  Isn't Crouton just another install mechanism?

Comment: @belacqua [everything related to installing Chrubuntu is off-topic by later discussion](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8025/how-to-resolve-conflicting-information-about-chrubuntu-policy-status?lq=1)

Comment: @Braiam Oli suggested "leave them open unless they're about installing".   What am I missing?  You have answers with fewer votes on both questions arguing that they are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found it.

In `/usr/local/bin/enter-chroot`

there are a few defines first.
e.g. `USERNAME='1000'`

where 1000 is the id of the user that unity is started with.
Since the user "root" always has id 0, switch it to 0 and it starts it as root.